# How to make JavaScript display an animated GIF for a few seconds, and then display an image?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Currently, I'm trying to build a Heads or Tails system in HTML, CSS, & JavaScript, but when you flip the coin, there is no animation to show the flipping. I've tried to use timeInterval and timeOut, but they don't work correctly, am I doing something wrong?

```js
function flipCoin() {
      var randomSide = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
        if (randomSide == 1) {
      document.getElementById("coinImg").src = 
    "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a0/2006_Quarter_Proof.png";
        } else {
          document.getElementById("coinImg").src = "https://www.coinhunts.com/wpcontent/uploads/2011/01/2005_CA_Proof.png";
        }
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Heads or Tails?</title>
          <link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'>
          <link rel="stylesheet" 
    href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
    integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" 
    crossorigin="anonymous">
          <link rel='icon' 
    href='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a0/2006_Quarter_Proof.png'>
            <script src='script.js'></script>
            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384- 
    J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"> 
            </script>
            <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" 
    integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" 
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            <script 
    src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" 
    integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" 
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      </head>

      <body>
        <div class='container'>
          <div class='row'>
            <h1 class='mx-auto'>Heads or Tails? JS</h1>
          </div>

      <div class='row'>
        <p class='mx-auto'>Click the Button Below to Flip a Coin!</p>
      </div>

      <div class='row'>
        <button onclick='flipCoin();' class='btn btn-primary btn-lg mx-auto' type='button'>Flip a Coin</button>
      </div>

      <div class='row'>
        <img href='' id='coinImg' class='mx-auto'/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [setTimeout()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp).

```
function coinSide() {
  var randomSide = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
    if (randomSide == 1) {
        document.getElementById("coinImg").src = "HEADS_URL.png";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("coinImg").src = "TAILS_URL.png";
    }
}

// Waits for 3 secs (3000ms) until executes the code
// Your random function is executed in setTimeout function
function flipCoin() {
    document.getElementById("coinImg").src = "COIN_FLIP_GIF_URL_HERE.gif";
    setTimeout(coinSide, 3000);
}
```